# IOS/Objective-C: Add One month to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am trying to add a month to an NSDate.  However, I discovered that the following code only works when the month number is between 1 and 11.  When you add 1 to 12, it does not automatically roll as a modulus to make 13->1 nor does it increment the year.

```
newStartDate = [cal dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth value:1 toDate:startDate options:0];
```

On the other hand, if you add seconds which does seem to work as modulus math, the seconds in a month vary by month and I would hate to have to code all those possibilities by hand.

```
   //following requires an input for days in month which can be
 28,29,30 or 31 depending on month and leap year status not to mention DST issues
     newStartDate = [newStartDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:30 * 24 * 60 * 60];
```

Can any one recommend a simple way to increment a date by one month?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Edit.

It turns out this behavior of the month incrementing up to 12 and then stopping in my project seems to be due to a loop in which it is embedded. So the method with options:0 by itself does increment higher units as expected.  Other options behave differently.

Comment: `dateByAddingUnit` increments and wraps units around to zero/one as expected unless you specify `NSCalendarWrapComponents`, then higher units are not incremented.

Comment: How can I specify default?  options:0 is not rolling over higher units and it does not accept nil

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: You are right.  I created a new project with just the date code and it does increment the higher units. In my project, the date incrementation is embedded in a complex while loop with switch statements that must be to blame.  The code increments the month up to 12 and then stops.  I will have to troubleshoot the loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you add 1 to 12, it does not automatically roll as a modulus to make 13->1 nor does it increment the year.

You're calling the wrong method. Call [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1409577-datebyaddingcomponents?language=objc) method instead:

```
let cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let d = cal.date(from: DateComponents(
    year: 2018, month: 12, day: 26, hour: 11, minute: 0, second: 0))!
let d2 = cal.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month:1), to: d)
d2 // Jan 26, 2019 at 11:00 AM
```

Comment: Actually the method used by OP should work as well and produce the same result.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, my original response was that the OP was just wrong. But then I realized that my own example didn't use the same method, so I covered my bets a little.

Comment: Matt, marking your answer correct as the method works and you also provided a link to the docs that was helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *actualDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComp = [NSDateComponents new];
[dateComp setMonth:1];
NSDate *dateAfterOneMonth = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComp toDate:actualDate options:0];
NSLog(@"Date after One Month: %@", dateAfterOneMonth);
```